# jquery hide and show link not working

Tags: jquery, html

Its not showing the title (show legend) to be able to switch between the legend and map. this does work with jQuery 1.8.3 but any version after that it doesn't work. Can anyone help on this?

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>


  <style type="text/css">
    .maplegend {
    display:none;
}
  </style>



<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".legend").hide();
    $(".maplegend").show();

    $('.maplegend').toggle(function () {
        $("#plus").text("Show Legend");
        $(".legend").show();
        $(".map").hide();

    }, function () {
        $("#plus").text("Show Map");
        $(".legend").hide();
        $(".map").show();
    });

});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" class="maplegend" id="plus" style="display: none;">Show Legend</a>

<div class="legend" style="display: none;">legend</div>
<div class="map">map</div>



</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `toggle` properly. It is not an event, it's an instruction that toggles visibility on/off. You're probably looking for something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isLegendVisible = false;
    $(".legend").hide();
    $(".maplegend").show();

    $('.maplegend').on('click', function () {
        if(isLegendVisible) {
            $("#plus").text("Show Map");
            $(".legend").hide();
            $(".map").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#plus").text("Show Legend");
            $(".legend").show();
            $(".map").hide();
        }
        isLegendVisible = ! isLegendVisible;
    });
});
```

PS: here's a link to the [toggle documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), if you still want to use it.

Comment: Ok got an issue with this... When you click on the link to show the legend, and you click to show maps again it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it the same link in both cases, ie `'.maplegend'`? If it's 2 separate links, you need 2 event handlers

Comment: its going to be the same link, I want to be able to switch between the legend and map.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is the function being called on both clicks? Can you put a breakpoint on the `if` line and verify you get to it every time you click, and that the value of isLegendVisible changes? (ps: I had a small typo in the last code line - could that be your issue?)

Comment: It's working now, I guess it was the typo. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool. Mark the answer as correct if it works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look this :)

```
$(".legend").css("visibility", "visible");
$(".legend").css("visibility", "hidden");
```